# Why am I seeing an "unknown" user at the bottom of a post?

Tags: support, display-names

By default, there is a username under each post:
[image]

I can click his icon and view their profile. But sometimes I see this kind of user:
[image]

I can't click on their icon, and I can't even access their profile by typing https://www.stackoverflow.com/user/6325897 (random number).

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [gobal Meta FAQ on account deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

When you delete your account...

> Content you've posted on the site [is owned by you, but licensed to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18221), and you therefore cannot request that it be deleted with your account. Your posts will be effectively dissociated from your account; your username will no longer show on them, but it will instead show your denormalized username (e.g. "user123456" where 123456 was the user ID of your account).